# How to change the class of an element in a JSP from the controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am trying to set the class of a list element (placed in a header file) according to the page I am on. The header file is imported into every page.

This project is using the Spring framework. I am new to Java Servlets and I am used to doing this in .NET in a straightforward way. I want to know what the most appropriate way to do it in Java/JSP is.

This is the header page (header.jsp):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainHeaderDiv" class="header main">
            <div class="header_resize">
                <div class="clr"></div>
                <div class="menu_nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="liHome"><a href="./Home.htm">Home</a></li>
                        <li id="liOrderInfo"><a href='./OrderInfo.htm'><span>Delivery Info</span></a></li>
                        <li id="liInvoice"><a href='./Invoice.htm'><span>Invoice Info</span></a></li>
                        <li id="liShipment"><a href='./Shipment.htm'><span>Sales Order Info</span></a></li>
                        <li id="liMaterial"><a href='./Material.htm'><span>Material Info</span></a></li>
                        <li id="liLogout"><a href="./logout.htm">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

One of the pages I am importing the above header into (home.jsp):

```
<%@include file="./header.jsp" %>
<div >
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content_resize">
                <div class="clr"></div>
                <div>
                    <div class="article">
                    <c:if test="${companyInfo != null}">
                        <h2>
                            <span>Company Profile</span>
                        </h2>
                        <b> <u>Company Information</u>
                        </b>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                 </c:if>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
    logger.debug("BEGIN");
    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */
    logger.debug("END");
    return "Home";
}
```

(Stripped out scripts and imports to make reading the actual code easier.)

So when I am on the home page, which is the best way to highlight the 'Home' menu option, if at all possible?

Comment: Nutshell: expose a variable indicating the page/section user is on. Use that variable in a JSP EL statement to indicate the section. There are myriad other ways to do it, but ultimately if it's a server-driven app, you'll expose a value, and check it in the view layer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, @DaveNewton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized that we can use EL directly in javascript code.

I passed the id of the li I wanted selected from the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        logger.debug("BEGIN");
        /*
        .
        .
        .
        */
        logger.debug("END");
        model.addAttribute("currPage", "liHome");
        return "Home";
    }
```

And used it in a javascript function on the header page like so:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var menuToActivate = '${currPage}';
    document.getElementById(menuToActivate).className = 'active';
};
```